# Consulta por fechas en C# MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp

buen dia tengo la siguiente duda con una consulta...

Me interesa traer los registros en una tabla de un dia, especificamente el dia que esta transcurriendo por ejemplo el de hoy que es **12/17/2021 desde las 7:00 AM** hasta el dia siguiente **12/18/2021 a las 7:00AM**

**En PHP lo realizo de esta manera.**

```
$StarDate = date("Y-m-d");
$EndDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 days"));

// QUERY PARA TABLA DE ULTIMOS EMPLEADOS EN REGISTRO DE ENTRADAS*/*///
$QueryEmpleadoLimit = "SELECT * FROM cafeteria.registros AS A
INNER JOIN cafeteria.empleados AS B
ON A.NumEmpleado = B.NumEmpleado
WHERE A.FechaRegistro >= '".$StarDate." 07:00:00' AND FechaRegistro <= '".$EndDate." 07:00:00'
ORDER By A.FechaRegistro DESC";
$RsltEmpLimit=mysqli_query($conexion,$QueryEmpleadoLimit);
```

Pero estoy aprendiendo **C#** y estoy perdido aqui.

```
// GET: Home
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("dd/MM/yyyy");
    var EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("dd/MM/yyyy");
    var cafeteriaDbContext = _context.registros.Include(r => r.Empleados)
                                               .Where(b => Convert.ToDateTime(b.FechaRegistro.ToShortDateString()) >= StartDate 
                                                && Convert.ToDateTime(b.FechaRegistro.ToShortDateString()) <= EndDate)
                                               .OrderByDescending(x => x.FechaRegistro);

    return View(await cafeteriaDbContext.ToListAsync());
}
```

Esta informacion la estoy mostrando en mi INDEX.

**Mi base de datos:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando declaras StarDate no le estás pasando ningún valor, necesitas obtener el valor del día de esta manera lo puedes hacer:

```
var StartDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + " 07:00:00");
var EndDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString() + " 00:07:00");
```

Así le concatenas la hora y luego lo conviertes a **DateTime**, para la fecha fin usas la función `AddDays(1)` y le mandas de parametro los días que le quieres sumar.

Luego realizas la consulta:

```
var cafeteriaDbContext = _context.registros.Include(r => r.Empleados)
                                           .Where(b => b.FechaRegistro >= StartDate 
                                            && b.FechaRegistro <= EndDate)
                                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.FechaRegistro);
```

Como tu campo es **DateTime** no necesitas hacerle conversión, solo la muy comparación.

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio ahora voy a investigar sobre esto de los date me confundia mucho

Comment: Ok bro, sigue adelante, bendiciones!.

Answer (score 0):

Es por que no asignas la fecha a tus variables intenta así:

```
   DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Today.AddHours(7);
   DateTime EndDate =StartDate.AddDays(1);
```

y en la consulta evita invocar a la funcion *Convert.ToDateTime()* y agrega un *ToList()* para iterar la consulta (Hasta que no lo iteremos, la consulta no se ha ejecutado todavía, y solo tenemos una expresión sobre una colección) así:

```
 var cafeteriaDbContext = _context.registros.Include(r => r.Empleados)
                .Where(b => b.FechaRegistro >= StartDate
                         && b.FechaRegistro <= EndDate)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.FechaRegistro).ToList();
```